# Title: Error: 'dict' object is not callable when using dict(zip(names, comps))

Tags: python, dictionary

I've come across a puzzling issue while trying to create a dictionary from two lists using the zip function in Python. From what I've seen in various tutorials and videos, the following syntax should work:

```
zipped = dict(zip(names, comps))
```

However, when I try to run this code, I'm encountering the following error:

```
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

I'm confused because this syntax is supposed to be correct. Has there been a recent change in Python that affects how dictionaries are created using zip? If this syntax is no longer valid, what's the alternative way to create a dictionary from two lists?

I searched this website and Google for a possible answer.

Comment: You've used `dict` as a variable earlier in your program. Don't do that. As you can see, it replaced the function.